# SQL Query to Sum Values on One Table and Select Names from Another table

Tags: sql, vb.net

Apologies for the poorly written title.

I have two tables. Table a with Student ID and Names and table b with Student ID, course and course cost

I want to be able to query the database so I can show the student name and total dollars spent on courses

So far I have this:

```
SELECT Student.fname, Student.lname, SUM(m.CourseCost) FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT StuID, CourseCost FROM Courses) AS m 
     INNER JOIN Student ON m.StuID = Student.ID;
```

Visual Studio throws an error when I try to run the query. I am using MS Access as the database. I think there is something wrong with my inner

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: you are using aggregate function you have to used group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT Student.fname, Student.lname, SUM(m.CourseCost) FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT StuID, CourseCost FROM Course) AS m 
     INNER JOIN Student ON m.StuID = Student.ID
     group by Student.fname, Student.lname
```

Or You can do by another way

```
select Student.fname, Student.lname, SUM(m.CourseCost) as  CourseCost
from Student
inner join Course m on Student.ID = m.StuID
group by Student.fname, Student.lname, m.StuID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select students.name , (select sum(cost) from course_details where student_id = students.id) as cost from students;
```

please note, this is a postgresql query. I believe the concept of subquery is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 SELECT fname+' '+lname Name,courseName , SUM(CourseCost) CourseCost
    FROM Student 
    INNER JOIN Courses ON Courses.StuID = Student.ID
    GROUP BY fname, lname ,courseName ;
```